# Creating full path link and crawl loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to parse a web site

I can generate a list of the interested link in the page using this code:

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="button-border"]/@href').extract()
```

However it returns a list with relative links, how can i create the absolute links, crawl all of them and apply another set of rules to every link?

Comment: i watched that thread before posting the question but i can't join the url and then pass a method for each url

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[urljoin(base_url, url) for url in response.xpath('//a[@class="button-border"]/@href').extract()]` where `base_url = response.url`.

Comment: it gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: `.extract()` returns a list, please debug your code first.